# Problem with dynamically generated JavaScript click events

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dom-events

I am trying to generate several divs which each should have a separate `onclick` handler. However, when I create multiple items in my application, all of the previous items have the same `onclick` event as the first one. Below is the code that generates the html based on an array or "Project" objects. How can I change this code to retain all individual click events?

```
var t1 = new Tracker(function(projects) {
        var tempElem;

        projectList.innerHTML = "";
        for(i in projects) {
            tempElem = document.createElement("div");
            tempElem.setAttribute("id", projects[i].id);
            tempElem.setAttribute("class", "project");
            tempElem.innerHTML = projects[i].name;
            projectList.appendChild(tempElem);
            document.getElementById(projects[i].id).onclick = function() {
                t1.setActiveProject(t1.getProjectById(projects[i].id)); };
        }
    }, setActiveProject);
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for Tracker so I can test this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery will save you lots of time and headaches.  I would recommend using it for what you are trying to accomplish.

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: Unfortunately, I am doing this project for a class, and can't use any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I need to accomplish this task without the use of frameworks. It is for a class that I am taking.